# Identify duplicate string patterns in elements in a list and create n new lists for each unique group of duplicates - python

Tags: python-2.7, list, duplicates

I have lists like this one:

```
[review_v001,
review_v002,
review_v003,
layerpack_review_v004,
layerpack_review_v001,
x_v001,
x_v002,
x_v003]
```

And I need regroup them into new lists grouped by the characters before the underscores, ie [:-5] to look like this:

```
[review_v001,
review_v002,
review_v003]

[layerpack_review_v004,
layerpack_review_v001]

[x_v001,
x_v002,
x_v003]
```

So to rephrase, I need to iterate through a given list, identify which elements of the list have the same prefix from the beginning of the string up to before the version number (such as _v001), and then reorganise these elements in to new lists where the grouping is based on this shared prefix.

This is one of my attempts, which succeeds to identify and almost group duplicates, except it doesn't name them correctly when it regroups them.

```
fullstringlst=
    [review_v001,
    review_v002,
    review_v003,
    layerpack_review_v004,
    layerpack_review_v001,
    x_v001,
    x_v002,
    x_v003]

prefixList = []
for s in fullstringlst:
    p = s[:-5]
    prefixList.append(p)
    sublists = []
    for item in set(prefixList):
        sublists.append([p] * prefixList.count(item))
    print sublists
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've added what I've tried to the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
fullstringlst = ['review_v001', 'review_v002', 'review_v003', 'layerpack_review_v004', 'layerpack_review_v001', 'x_v001', 'x_v002', 'x_v003']

for s1 in fullstringlst:
    similar_strs = []
    for s2 in fullstringlst:
        if s1[:-5] == s2[:-5]:
            similar_strs.append(s2)
    print(similar_strs)
```

Comment: I'm glad. You can probably clean it up a bit, but some logic is there for you.